# AIX Server statistic commands

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I ran the lparstat command and got this output.. Need to know which field to parse for overall CPU allocation, CPU usage, free CPU for this AIX server and how to parse that information..

```
System configuration: type=Shared mode=Uncapped smt=4 lcpu=12 mem=24576MB psize=5 ent=0.30

%user  %sys  %wait  %idle physc %entc  lbusy  vcsw phint  %nsp  %utcyc
----- ----- ------ ------ ----- ----- ------ ----- ----- -----  ------
 37.4  30.4    4.0   28.2  0.96 320.0   22.0 14315232399 16476954189   101   1.04
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error-message/symptom did you get? Which manuals have you read?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I read the description of lparstat from IBM's knowledge center, and it explained that %sys
Indicates the percentage of the entitled processing capacity used while executing at the system level (kernel) %user
Indicates the percentage of the entitled processing capacity used while executing at the user level (application).
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lparstat.htm I want the overall CPU usage, and free CPU. Don't know which fields represent the ones I want.

Comment: I tried the awk command to parse out %user field but this is what I'm getting `lparstat | awk {'print$1'}` and I have gotten `System

%user
-----
37.4` but not sure if user is the one I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

As AIX lives inside LPar, it can operate with provided by PowerVM (Power hypervisor) amount of entitled capacity (EC), which is actually only a time slice. There are four possible types of CPU time allocation to LPar:

- [1] Dedicaded (really dedicated). Minimum quantity is one core. All available core time.
- [2] Dedicated (with donation ability). Minimum quantity is a core. All available core time IF it is used more than 80% of time.
- [3] Shared (Capped). Minimum quantity is 1/20 (Power8/9) of a single core time. LPar will consume not more than guaranteed CPU capacity (that is, Entitled Capacity). LPar will share all unused CPU with other LPars.
- [4] Shared (Uncapped). Same as [3], but allowed to consume more than Entitled Capacity if [a lot of conditions].

Because of PowerVM's flexible CPU time management, every AIX native statistic utility includes two additional parameters:

- Entitled Capacity. This is how much CPU *time* of a single core is *guaranteed* to LPar during each time slice
- Physical Consumption. This is how much of guaranteed core time is *consumed* by LPar during each time slice

PowerVM will review each 10ms CPU time dedication to each LPar. Based on your example, there is [4] CPU dedication option used, with 0.3 core entitled to LPar

> System configuration: type=**Shared** mode=**Uncapped** smt=4 lcpu=12 mem=24576MB psize=5 **ent=0.30**

This means that your LPar is *guaranteed* with 0.3 CPU time and *allowed* to consume (if there are any available) up to number of Virtual CPU count (specified in LPar's profile), lcpu/smt or 12/4=3 -> up to 3.0 CPU time. This is the same as 1000% of Entitled capacity and up to 3.0 Physical Consumption (physc).

So, if you need to know how much CPU is used, you should take a look at Physical Consumption (physc) and Entitled Capacity (ent, %ent) fields.
Lets say, in your example you have

> System configuration: type=Shared mode=Uncapped smt=4 lcpu=12 mem=24576MB psize=5 **ent=0.30**
>
> %user  %sys  %wait  %idle **physc %entc**  lbusy  vcsw phint  %nsp  %utcyc
>
> ---
>
> 37.4  30.4    4.0   28.2  **0.96 320.0**   22.0 14315232399 16476954189   101   1.04

Your LPar consumes 3.2 times more CPU than it is guaranteed, because %entc=320.
This may be absolutely normal, depends on your overcommitment strategy. In general considerations, if you see %entc lower than 100% that would mean your LPar is underloaded, and more than 100% means LPar is overloaded.

As for parsing, I'd cut off all letters from output with `grep -v [a-z]`, then  grep for numbers with `grep [0-9,.]` and print column #6 which stands for %entc (or any other based on your need):  `awk '{print $6}'`

```
lparstat | grep -v [a-z] | grep [0-9,.] | awk '{print $6}'
```

would return 320.0

This IBM course may be useful for you: https://www-03.ibm.com/services/learning/ites.wss/zz-en?pageType=course_description&cc=&courseCode=AN31G

P.S. If you need to know your LPar's CPU Profile settings from AIX side, you can use `lparstat -i` command

P.P.S You probably should take a look at LPars profiles/weights or review consolidation policy on your physical machine. There is too much phantom interrupts (phint) which may mean LPar is competing with others for shared resources (CPU).